# Make all methods in a WCF service all be GET's with the same body wrap style

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I would like to make all the methods I am adding to my WCF service have the following behaviour:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Instead of having to add these attributes to every single [OperationContract] method is there a way I can configure this service wide?

Comment: I dont think so....and it is [Operation Contract]... plus y do you want that kind of a thing anyways, this is the most common approach plus it gives you a control over URI templates and behaviors on method declaration itself...

Comment: I want all my message bodies the same for instance. It seems weird to have to do that on each method I expose. Sure for URI's I can understand it if they are different (or need a different behaviour from what is the over all default) but why type in the same thing over and over again that never changes?

Comment: in your case it is not changing....but that is not the case every time you write a service....

Comment: Yep. But it would be nice if you could set a default at service level and then override it for those operational contracts where necessary.